# How to create a simple setTimeout loop

Tags: jquery, loops, settimeout

I simply need to create an infinite loop through 3 variations of an element. This is what I have so far:

```
    var count = 1;
    setTimeout(transition, 2000);

    function transition() {

        if(count == 1) {
            $('#ele').html('variation 2');
            var count = 2;

        } else if(count == 2) {
            $('#ele').html('variation 3');
            var count = 3;

        } else if(count == 3) {
            $('#ele').html('variation 1');
            var count = 1;
        }

        setTimeout(transition, 2000);

    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try that :

```
var count = 1;

function transition() {

    if(count == 1) {
        $('#ele').html('variation 2');
         count = 2;

    } else if(count == 2) {
        $('#ele').html('variation 3');
         count = 3;

    } else if(count == 3) {
        $('#ele').html('variation 1');
        count = 1;
    }

}
setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want an infinite loop, you should be using `setInterval()`.  This will run an infinite loop, each time running the next variation:

```
var i=0;

setInterval(function() {
    switch(i++%3) {
        case 0: alert("variation 1");
        break;
        case 1: alert("variation 2");
        break;
        case 2: alert("variation 3");
        break;
    }

}, 2000);
```

If you later decide you need to stop the repeating code, store the return value when you set the interval and clear it:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    ...
}, 1000);

clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is the best solution:**

The *clearTimeout()* method clears a timer set with the *setTimeout()* method.

```
(function(){
    var timer, count=1;
    function transition(){
        clearTimeout(timer);

        switch(count){
            case 1: count = 2; break;
            case 2: count = 3; break;
            case 3: count = 1; break;
        }

        $('#ele').html('variation ' + count);

        timer = setTimeout(transition, 2000);
    }
    transition();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `var` in front of your `count` variable inside the `transition` function. Remove them and the outer `count` variable will hold its value.

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to use **setTimeout** and **clearTimeout** to create a loop 
you should use something like this structure for your loop

```
var count = 1;
var timer = setTimeout( function(){
    transaction();
} , 2000);

function transition() {

    if(count == 1) {
        $('#ele').html('variation 2');
        count = 2;

    } else if(count == 2) {
        $('#ele').html('variation 3');
        count = 3;

    } else if(count == 3) {
        $('#ele').html('variation 1');
        count = 1;
    }
    //if(condition for continue) 
    setTimeout(transition, 2000);
    //else if you want to stop the loop
    //clearTimeout(timer, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**My best way in real life jobs is to "Forget Basic Loops"** in this case and use this combination of "setInterval" includes "setTimeOut"s:

```
    function iAsk(lvl){
        var i=0;
        var intr =setInterval(function(){ // start the loop 
            i++; // increment it
            if(i>lvl){ // check if the end round reached.
                clearInterval(intr);
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".imag").prop("src",pPng); // do first bla bla bla after 50 millisecond
            },50);
            setTimeout(function(){
                 // do another bla bla bla after 100 millisecond.
                seq[i-1]=(Math.ceil(Math.random()*4)).toString();
                $("#hh").after('<br>'+i + ' : rand= '+(Math.ceil(Math.random()*4)).toString()+' > '+seq[i-1]);
                $("#d"+seq[i-1]).prop("src",pGif);
                var d =document.getElementById('aud');
                d.play();                   
            },100);
            setTimeout(function(){
                // keep adding bla bla bla till you done :)
                $("#d"+seq[i-1]).prop("src",pPng);
            },900);
        },1000); // loop waiting time must be >= 900 (biggest timeOut for inside actions)
    }
```

PS: Understand that the real behavior of (setTimeOut): they all will start in same time "the three bla bla bla will start counting down in the same moment" so make a different timeout to arrange the execution.

PS 2: the example for timing loop, but for a reaction loops you can use events, promise async await ..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-count]").each(function () {
        counter($(this), .5)
    });

    function counter(el, speed) {
        let number = el.data("count"),
            count_type = el.data("count-type"),
            i = count_type === "up" ? 0 : number;

        let inter_val = setInterval(function () {
            el.text(i);
            i = count_type === "up" ? i + 1 : i - 1;
            if ((count_type === "up" && i > number) || (count_type === "down" && i < 0))
                clearInterval(inter_val);
        }, speed);
    }
});
```

```css
span {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    color: #333;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>COUNT UP EXAMPLE</p>
<span data-count="1650" data-count-type="up"></span>
<span data-count="2500" data-count-type="up"></span>
<span data-count="985" data-count-type="up"></span>
<br>
<p>COUNT DOWN EXAMPLE</p>
<span data-count="1650" data-count-type="down"></span>
<span data-count="2500" data-count-type="down"></span>
<span data-count="985" data-count-type="down"></span>
```