# can a rails 3.2 app on heroku keep connection alive while background task runs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku kills a dyno process that runs more than 30 seconds. Some of our tasks can take a minute or so.

We run such tasks in the background via delayed job. The background task sets a `task_is_done` flag in the Foo model when completed.

What is the best way to have a user's browser check every 10 seconds if `task_is_done` is true, so the user's view is updated periodically as the task processes, and we avoid the heroku timeout for long running tasks?

(A brute force approach is use a meta tag to tell the browser to reload the page every 10 seconds, and have the controller for that page check the status of `task_is_done`. Aside from the code stench, it also doesn't work with every browser.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery in the browser and make an ajax call to check the flag every 10 seconds utlizing setInterval. An example of setInterval is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081078/2680964