# JQuery infinite animation

Tags: jquery

I try to do a infinite JQuery animation, but this, do just 1 animation and stop.... I try to use setTimeout to resolve it but it didn't work.
do you know why?

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="homeAnimation">
        <div id="A">soins</div>
        <div id="B">formation</div>
        <div id="C">contact</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function anim( selector, firstDelay) {
console.log(selector);
$(selector).animate({
    'margin-left':'100%'
}, 0).delay(firstDelay)
.animate({
            'margin-left': '50%',
            'transform: scale':'2'
        }, 1000).delay(2000)
        .animate({
            'margin-left': '-7%',
            'transform: scale':'1'
        }, 1000);
        return;
    }
    setTimeout( anim("#homeAnimation #A", 0 * 8000), 10000);
    setTimeout( anim("#homeAnimation #B", 1 * 8000), 10000);
    setTimeout( anim("#homeAnimation #C", 2 * 8000), 10000);`
```

Comment: Why not just use a gif?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to achieve when the text scrolled over. But take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080983/how-to-create-a-simple-settimeout-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it infinite:

```
function anim( selector, firstDelay) {
    console.log(selector);
    $(selector).animate({
        'margin-left':'100%'
    }, 0).delay(firstDelay)
    .animate({
                'margin-left': '50%',
                'transform: scale':'2'
            }, 1000).delay(2000)
            .animate({
                'margin-left': '-7%',
                'transform: scale':'1'
            }, 1000);
            return;
        }
        setTimeout( anim("#homeAnimation #A", 0 * 8000), 100000);
        setTimeout( anim("#homeAnimation #B", 1 * 8000), 100000);
        setTimeout( anim("#homeAnimation #C", 2 * 8000), 100000);
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work for me change to 100s didn't do anything, it's strange that the function is called just once time